# REACT-NATIVE-SCREENS CompileSdkVersion not found Error

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-screens

[image]I'm getting a CompileSdkVersion error when I install react-native-screens to my project. I have followed the changes needed to make react-native screens work from the documentation and  controlled if there is version mistake but it seems like there isn't any! Could you help me out. Thank you in advance

The versions I am working on are:

``

```
    dependencies": {
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
        "react": "18.1.0",
        "react-native": "0.70.6",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2"
```

`

This is my android/build.gradle config
`

```
    ext {
            buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
            minSdkVersion = 21
            compileSdkVersion = 31
            targetSdkVersion = 31
}
```

`

This is my android/app/build.gradle config
`

`

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.navigationtrial"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

`

This is the default config in node_modules\react-native-screens\android\build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

android {
compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 28)

```
    
    defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 21)
            targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 22)
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
```

`

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the issue?

Comment: yes ofcourse I will

Comment: You should remove these damn folders. `rm -rf android/build android/app/build`. And rebuild the app.

Comment: its giving ,e this error  A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.